# Passport stamps from london -ams-london

Tags: passport-stamps

I am an indian passport holder and i am in london right now on tourist visa and i am travelling to amsterdam for 3 days by flight and coming back to london . I was wondering that when i come to london from amsterdam they will stamp my passport again or they ask immigration questions again ?

Comment: For Americans, at least, the or is not exclusive.  I would guess the same holds true for other non-EU nationalities.

Answer (score 6):

You will pass through immigration in both directions. Be sure that your UK visa will allow you to exit and reenter.

How much scrutiny will be given to you relative to your inital arrival I cannot say. Certainly a visit to continental europe would not be an unusal thing for a genuine tourist to do.